# I purchase the domain and how can I have more than two urls under this domain?

Tags: url, dns, namecheap

I am trying to host the webapp and the company page under one domain like

Google has

https://www.google.com/
https://support.google.com/

I thought it was two different domains and I've searched for abc.myfirm.io (example) and it does not look like I need to purchase a domain to have that setup.

I am currently using NameCheap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to register a separate domain with a domain name registrar. You can just create a DNS entry for the subdomain. If the different domains are all aliases for the primary domain (myfirm.io), then use a `CNAME` record to point the subdomains to myfirm.io. If they are intended to be separate services, create an `A` record to point the subdomain to the IP it's hosted on.